# The name 'List' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'List'

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I am facing a error while using "List" in dart. I am using Visual Studio Code. I don't know why is it showing red mark under this List keyword? Can anyone give me a solution to get rid of this?

Please see the screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Did you maybe define something on top that is called "List"?

Comment: Can you hover on the list and see where the list is defined?

Comment: Post code that can reproduce your problem, *not screenshots*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

There is a function named `List` somewhere. Try to find it and just rename it to something else more specific as it conflicts with the already existing type [`List`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html) from Dart.

Tip: On VSCode you can go to the definition of a type/function/var by just pressing `Ctrl + click` (`Cmd + click`) over it.

Comment: Dear lepsch, Thanks for your feedback. But there is no function name like List in my dart page. List has been used as a Future return type . U can check my attachment. Let's see one of my function user here:

Comment: Future<List<IPOSubscription>> getSubscribers(investorcode, comid) async {
    List<IPOSubscription> ipoSubscriptions = [];
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'http://159.120.3.12:5000/getSubscribers/' +
            investorcode +
            '/' +
            comid));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
    return body.map((json) => IPOSubscription.fromJson(json)).toList();
    //return ipoSubscriptions;
  }

Comment: Would you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73009350/edit) your question and copy-paste the module imports of this file into the question itself?

Comment: import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shel_apps/models/fund_model.dart';
import 'package:shel_apps/models/ipo_model.dart';
import 'package:shel_apps/models/listIPO.dart';
import 'package:shel_apps/models/user_model.dart';

Comment: Is there some exactly named `List` declared in the module `package:shel_apps/models/listIPO.dart'`?

Comment: Yes in this dart class i have used a class name "ListIPO"..

Comment: I have changed this class name but error is same....

Comment: every time I pressed the quickFix on List it gives me to import dart:core however this library is already imported on the top of my dart page!!!

Comment: Most probably when renaming `List` to `ListIPO` it renamed the Dart standard modules too. You'd need to reinstall flutter.

Comment: I have uninstalled flutter from vscode and reinstalled again. But error in List remains same...i am unable to find out the reason brother..pls help me

Comment: So weird! Is it possible to share your repository URL?